# Should I install a different version of node.js to a server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, node.js

I develop in a Microsoft environment, so I'm used to the idea of a developer mode and an optimised server mode to different pieces of software.

If I want to run a node application on a server, should I install anything differently to the server machine apart from the latest from nodejs.org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, there is only a single version of NodeJS.

So, no, there is no other version for you to install in your production environment. Depending on your application you might want to set the environment variable `NODE_ENV` to `production` though.